# How can I configure a SPFx webpart project to launch in a specific browser during development?

Tags: spfx-webparts, development-enviroment

I want to use the Brave browser with a specific user profile to work on multiple SharePoint sites. Currently, when I run the gulp serve command, the webpart project launches in the OS default browser, which opens the workbench of the SharePoint site I have configured. However, I need to use separate browser sessions for each SharePoint site I work on.

When I try to use the Site Workbench URL in a different browser, it doesn't work. How can I configure my SPFx webpart project to launch in the Brave browser with the specific user profile I need?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special for this into SPFx solution.

You can append below in URL of the the page in different browser session where you have logged in with different user:

```
?debugManifestsFile=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4321%2Ftemp%2Fmanifests.js&loadSPFX=true
```

Now you can edit the page and add the web part and then you can debug the code of your web part with this session of the browser.

See below link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-modern-pages